# SQL procedure to select merge

Tags: sql, procedures

My procedure is:

```
create procedure "news"
as
select newsdate,COUNT(B.id) as total from news B
where B.newsyear < GETDATE()
Group by B.newsdate

select newsdate,COUNT(B.id) as total from news B 
where B.status='WAITING' and B.cancel='1'
Group by B.newsdate
```

Results:

```
newsdate   total
2011       4
2010       8

newsdate   total
2011       2
2010       3
```

How can I merge year totals to obtain this result set:

```
newsdate   total
2011       6       {4 + 2}
2010       11      {8 + 3}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a simple or statement (if it's indeed the same table):

```
select newsdate,COUNT(B.id) as total
from news B
where B.newsyear < GETDATE()
   or B.status='WAITING' and B.cancel='1'
Group by B.newsdate
```

or using union all + a sum aggregate (if it's different tables):

```
select newsdate, sum(total) as total from (
  select newsdate,COUNT(B.id) as total from news B where B.newsyear < GETDATE()
  Group by B.newsdate
  union all
  select newsdate,COUNT(B.id) as total from news B where B.status='WAITING' and B.cancel='1'
  Group by B.newsdate
  ) as rows
group by newsdate
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select newsdate,COUNT(B.id) as total 
from news B 
where ( B.newsyear < GETDATE() )
or ( B.status='WAITING' and B.cancel='1' )
Group by B.newsdate
```